# How to use Random C#?

Tags: c#, random

I know how to use Random Class in a basic way but i want to use it in such a way that I would get a random number which is < 200 or >300 not any random number between 200-300.
So how can I do it.

```
rand = new Random();
```

Comment: Greater than 300 to infinite?

Comment: Generally infinity doesn't work well when you actually try to use it in code.

Comment: You need to tell us what ranges the numbers should fall into.  A range includes both an upper and a lower bounds.  And further note that you cannot have a uniform distribution (the default) over an infinite range (though there are other distributions that can).

Comment: ok From 0 to 600 but not from 200-300

Comment: Initial thought with your adjustment: loop while rand >200 & <301 rand.Next()...

Comment: Call rand() * 600 and if the result is between 200,300 then add 100

Comment: Nice Austin I am going with your idea thanks.

Comment: @AssafLavie that will not generate a uniform distribution

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd you're right, but I reckoned this would be good enough for the OP. If uniformity is really important he can do rand* 500() and add 300 if the results is between 200,300

Comment: @AssafLavie - no, add 100

Comment: Once the criteria forced me to think this through and read the answers I had to rethink and remodel this mentally. +1 for making me think about uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , this is use for PURE Randomness.

```
    Random rand=new Random();
    int value= rand.next(0,600);
    while(value>=200 && value<=300)
      {
        value=rand.next(0,600);
      }
```

For me , this makes me feel the number generated is random , no more algorithm inside.

Hope it works

Comment: This could take a while

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd 1/6 chance to get 200-300 in first time , 1/36 chance to get 200-300 both times , 1/216 to get it 3 times. This shouldn't take longer than a second even if it's your most unlucky day.

Comment: I know, it is just a habit that I got into when working at high performance stuff to try and not waste time/resources when not needed.

Comment: Just be aware that if the range that should be excluded become wider these chances will be very different. Imagine generating numbers between 0 to 100 and 900 to 1000 this way.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Thank you for your advice. I'm generating code for a specific use Xb.

Answer (score 5):

You could generate between 0 and 500 and add 100 to any number greater than 200.

```
var rand = new Random();
int value = rand.Next(0,500);
if(value>=200)
{
    value+=100;
}
```

Comment: Or why not subtract 100 for that matter. Or, why not try another random number when a number in the unwanted range is generated...

Comment: To keep a uniform distribution. But, yes, there are may ways

Comment: OK, but by always adding 100 aren't you going to lose uniform distribution?

Comment: @AustinFrench - no, because it will shift all values

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50585/uniform-distribution Some follow up questions if you don't mind:

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way i see is to move the random number if it goes to 200-300.

```
var rand = new Random();
int value = rand.Next(0,500);
if(value>=200 && value <=300)
{
    value+=300;
}
```

Comment: @ClickRick no. If the value is between 200 and 300 i move it to 500-600. I don't move the values 300-500.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Why?  300-400 is not in the if-clause. This is also another nice way to do t.

Answer (score 0):

try this recursive approach

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        var number = GetRandomInt(random, 0, 500);
    }

    static int GetRandomInt(Random random, int min, int max)
    {
        var randomInt = random.Next(min, max);
        if (randomInt < 200 || randomInt > 300)
        {
            return randomInt;
        }
        return GetRandomInt(random, min, max);
    }
```